# What is returned by queryPurchaseHistoryAsync?

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I am looking at the new billing library for Android, can't seem to find what json is returned in a purchase object by this method.

Can someone point me at a reference?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the [BillingClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.html) docs:

> **queryPurchaseHistoryAsync**
>
> (String skuType,
> PurchaseHistoryResponseListener listener)
>
> Returns the most recent
> purchase made by the user for each SKU, even if that purchase is
> expired, canceled, or consumed.

Comment: I'm looking for the full json or a sample of it. IE is developer payload included? what about expiry time for subs? what are the exact names of those fields? etc